# How to replace certain Greek letters in mtpro2 with their counterparts from newtxmath

Tags: math-mode, fonts, mtpro, newtxmath

I use `mtpro2` package in my article for writing math and Times Roman for text. The question is how to use certain Greek letters (like `\gamma` which I see better in `newtxmath`) from `newtxmath` instead of those in `mtpro2`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[zswash,lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

Law of Quadratic Reciprocity:

Some text goes here ...
\begin{equation}
f(z) = 50\sigma \times E_0 e^{-\gamma x} \cos(\omega t-\beta z) \mathbf{a}_x \quad \mathbf{A} + \Gamma
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

For `gamma`, the problem was solved with the the answer by @egreg below, but for `Gamma` it wasn't. I tried the following workaround:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{newtxletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{newtxletters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{newtxletters}{0}
```

but it gave me the italic version of `Gamma`. I know that `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` have different (and incompatible) output encodings, but there must be some workaround. Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\gamma \ \bm{\gamma} \ \Gamma \ \bm{\Gamma} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

But the required is this:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Define a new symbol font using the font of `newtxmath` and tell TeX to take `\gamma` from it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[zswash,lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{newtxletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{newtxletters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{newtxletters}{13}

\begin{document}

Law of Quadratic Reciprocity: $\gamma\ne\beta$
\begin{equation}
f(z) = 50\sigma \times E_0 e^{-\gamma x} \cos(\omega t-\beta z) \mathbf{a}_x \quad \mathbf{A} + \Gamma
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the same without the change.

[image]

Comment: @ egreg The solution does not work in case of `\mathbf{\gamma}`. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: @latexfan Of course it doesn't; `mtpro2` has a special setup for that; it uses different specially tailored output encodings. And no, it's incompatible with the standard encoding used by `newtxmath`. But `\bm{\gamma}` will do.

Comment: @ egreg - Nice, it works for `\bm{\gamma}`, but for uppercase `\Gamma` it doesn't. I guess I should `\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{newtxletters}{<number>}`?

Comment: I tried `\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{newtxletters}{0}`, but it gave me the `italic` version ... any more ideas?

Comment: @latexfan What's the problem with `\Gamma`? They are the same!

Comment: The upright bold `\Gamma` is incorrectly encoded, @egreg. It appears as two shifted `Gamma`s.

Comment: @latexfan As I said, `mtpro2` uses different font encodings; you want to do an almost impossible thing. In any case, the uppercase `\Gamma` is the same with newtx and mtpro2, as far as I can see.

Comment: @egreg can you please tell how to do the same for replacing the `\lambda` from `mtpro2` with that from `amsmath` ?

Comment: @Aim `amsmath` doesn't define any character.

Comment: @egreg I found the name of the package. It is `fontenc` and not `amsmath`.

Comment: @Aim No, neither `fontenc`.

Comment: @egreg I want to replace `\lambda` from `mtpro2` with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K15WE.png). I am not able find which package offers it.

Comment: @Aim Oh, the standard Computer Modern symbol? Do `\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}` `\SetSymbolFont{cmletters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}` `\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{cmletters}{"15}`

Comment: @egreg Thank you! Also, can you please tell where can I find the numbers that correspond to different Greek alphabets for e.g. `''15` corresponds to `\lambda`  and `13`  corresponds to `\gamma`.

Comment: @Aim Look for the `fontmath.ltx` file on your system.

Comment: @egreg Thank you once again!