# Replace an upright Greek math alphabet in mtpro2

Tags: math-mode, fonts, mtpro, newtxmath

I need to replace the `gamma` and upright uppercase `Gamma` alphabets in [`mtpro2`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2) with their counterparts from [`newtxmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) in both normal and bold styles. I asked a related question, viz., [How to replace certain Greek letters in mtpro2 with their counterparts from newtxmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245886/how-to-replace-certain-greek-letters-in-mtpro2-with-their-counterparts-from-newt), but got half the answer. For `\gamma`, the problem is solved, but for `\Gamma` it isn't. I tried the following workaround:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{newtxletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{newtxletters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{newtxletters}{0}
```

but it gave me the italic version of `\Gamma`. I know that `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` have different (and incompatible) output encodings, but there must be some workaround. To summarize, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\gamma \ \bm{\gamma} \ \Gamma \ \bm{\Gamma} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Which outputs

[image: gotten]

but the required is

[image: wanted]

Comment: Note that if you have access to the "full" (rather than the "lite") version of the `mtpro2` package, you will have access to the font package's bold-Gamma symbol. In my opinion, the regular-weight and bold-weight versions of the `\Gamma`  glyphs produced by the `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` packages are extremely close. What are you trying to achieve by using the newtxmath-based glyphs instead of the mtpro2-based glyphs? Surely there's no meaningful difference in readability.