# Greek characters inside \mathrm and \mathbf cause garbled output

Tags: fonts, errors, greek, mtpro

Within a TeX file, the author coded the Greek characters inside the `\mathrm` and `\mathbf` as shown below:

```
$\mathrm{4 km\cdot (0,157+j  0,072)\omega/km}$
```

When I use the `mtpro2` package, I obtain the below garbled output for the Greek characters:

[image: Depiction of the valid output and the obtained garbled output.]

Is possible to get the correct rendered output?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[numbers]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
  without \verb+\mathrm  -->+ 


 $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu$ \bigskip

   with \verb+  \mathrm  -->+ 

  $\mathrm{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}$\bigskip


   with \verb+  \mathbf  -->+ 

  $\mathbf{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot yes we can use it `\boldsymbol`, unfortunately author has used so many places `\mathrm` and `\mathbf`, i cant able to trace wherever is occuring, so i need a error to throw those greek characters inside the `\mathrm/\mathbf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test because I don't own mtpro2.sty but perhaps this will help

```
\documentclass[numbers]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mtpro2}

\makeatletter
\@tfor\x:=\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu
\do{\count@\numexpr\x-"7000\relax
    \expandafter\mathchardef\x=\count@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  without \verb+\mathrm  -->+ 


 $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu$ \bigskip

   with \verb+  \mathrm  -->+ 

  $\mathrm{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}$\bigskip


   with \verb+  \mathbf  -->+ 

  $\mathbf{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}$

\end{document}
```

UPDATE. Here is version with intelligent Greek letters. I can not test the mtpro2 with bold math. I could test the lite version on overleaf.

For the full version uncomment the commented out parts in `\expandafter\edef\x...`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\AtBeginDocument{\setbox0\hbox{$\mathrm{\xdef\MATHRMFAM{\the\fam}}%
                                \mathbf{\xdef\MATHBFFAM{\the\fam}}$}}

\makeatletter
\@tfor\x:=\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu
\do{\edef\y{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            \@gobble\expandafter\string\x}%
    \expandafter\let\csname ORIG\y\expandafter\endcsname\x
    \expandafter\edef\x{\noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\fam=\noexpand\MATHRMFAM\space
                        \expandafter\noexpand\csname up\y\endcsname
                          %\noexpand\else
                          %\noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\fam=\noexpand\MATHBFFAM\space
                          %\expandafter\noexpand\csname bmup\y\endcsname
                        \noexpand\else
                        \expandafter\noexpand\csname ORIG\y\endcsname
                        \noexpand\fi
                          %\noexpand\fi
                       }%
  }%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  without \verb+\mathrm  -->+ 


 $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu$ \bigskip

   with \verb+  \mathrm  -->+ 

  $\mathrm{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}$\bigskip


   with \verb+  \mathbf  -->+ 

  $\mathbf{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}$\bigskip

   with \verb+  \mathit  -->+ 

$\mathit{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu}

\end{document}
```

Produces on overleaf (I didn't even install lite version of mtpro on my disk)

[image]

The `\mathit` test is for comparison. With full mtpro and the commented-out lines uncommented you should see (if I believe info on macro names from doc) the upright **bold** Greek letters when using `\mathbf`.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with a lack of defined upright and bold Greek symbols, within the default character set of `mtpro2` that the package loads. This is partially discussed in a related [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246384/134641), and a hint toward a solution is provided by [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30550/134641).

While there are likely other ways of resolving this, one possible way is to ensure that both valid upright and bold Greek character sets are available, to allow `\mathrm` and `\mathbf` to function as expected.

One way of accomplishing this is to load [`mathdesign`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign) (*before* `mtpro2`) and [`isomath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/isomath), with the `OMLmathrm` and `OMLmathbf` options (*after* `mtpro2`), as shown below and on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vmstqtrrxtvc):

```
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{mtpro2}

\usepackage[OMLmathrm, OMLmathbf]{isomath}
```